# How to validate CheckBox in Kentico 8.2?

Tags: kentico

I am working in Kentico 8.2, and I want the user to have to accept all of the terms and conditions. For this, I am using a check box. If that check box is unchecked then user will not be able to submit the form.

This is not achievable through Kentico help which says that I can achieve it by making the check box multiple choice. I have done this and it works but I want the check box's own validation to work.

I cannot attach a picture here otherwise I would show you guys what I have done so far.

If anyone has a solution then please help.

Answer (score 7):

Do you use the basic Kentico forms module?

You can use Validation on a field.

in the Forms module:

- new field "**conditions**"
- check "Required"
- default value unchecked
- Validation "Add validation rule"

  - select General condition
  - Enter text > press edit and in the code tab add the following macro:

  `{%conditions.Value == 1%}`

  - add an error message
  - dont forget to press **Apply** and save the field

This worked in my sample.